# What to choose between Action bar or TabLayout?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm developing for ICS. In a test activity, I need to display a top bar which has the number of questions. User can jump to any question by clicking on any question number in **top bar**. Now after a considerable research, I was going for horizontal listview but I guess thats not gonna work for me. I have two options now, either use Action bar or tablayout. Now which one to choose, I'll be developing in both of them for the first time.

See image below to get an idea of what I am looking for  - 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the TableLayout will be the best option. So that you can additionally insert Views and can constomize it as you want

Comment: In which one views can be added dynamically? And please redirect me to some example of it.

Answer (score 0):

Table layout if you are looking for backward compatibility or else actionbar.

Comment: ActionBar can be totally backward compatible, you just have to use ActioBar Sherlock

Comment: ActionBar can be totally backward compatible, you just have to use ActioBar Sherlock.
I think that the choice is between a view control in your actionbar (cf http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html ) or implementing a table layout.
A table layout would probably be preferable if your list is 15 elements long

Comment: In which one views can be added dynamically? And please redirect me to some example of it.